# Laravel 4 - command in shared hosting cron job

Tags: laravel, cron, command

i've developed a simply new command by using

```
php artisan command:make MyCommand
```

and after, i've registered it in app/start/artisan.php in this way

```
Artisan::add('MyCommand');
```

i've no problem to call command locally by

```
php artisan command:MyCommand
```

but i've errors when i try to call the command by using a cron job
the cron job is done in this way

```
/usr/bin/php -c /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/dferdinw/php.ini /home2/dferdinw/public_html/ff4b/artisan command:MyCommand
```

but i receive this error

```
[InvalidArgumentException] 
Command "command:MyCommand" is not defined. 
Did you mean this? 
command:make
```

Any idea???

Comment: Could you please post your command class? (maybe you missed something with the configuration).

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

If this is working locally and not on your server then check to see if your files are updated on your server.

---

Seems like if it works from the command line it should work from Cron. Try adding

```
echo __DIR__;
```

to the fire method and run it again manually it verify you've got the right DIR.

If it's not working from the command line make sure you named your command by changing the

```
protected $name = 'command:MyCommand';
```

The generator does NOT fill this out for you.

Also try

```
Artisan::add(new MyCommand);
```

And run

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

For you cron job try

```
cd /home2/dferdinw/public_html/ff4b/; php artisan command:MyCommand;
```

Comment: Thanks Brian,the DIR is ok.. and also the $name value !! 
When i execute from cron job

php /folders.../artisan list

in the list doesn't appear command:MyCommand ... 

it seems like if Artisan::add('MyCommand') doesn't execute !

Comment: Added a few more things to try.

Comment: yes i've already tried with dump-autoload .. but it doesn't work!

Comment: Weird. It seems like it running a different installation of Laravel. Do you have it installed in any other dirs?

Comment: Laravel is installed in standard dir.. maybe is a strange configuration of web server??? i don't know!!

also with the cron job modified in your last post nothing change!

Really I don't understand!

Comment: Are you able to ssh into your server? Also can you look at the files on your server and make sure you latest changes are there?

Comment: No Brian, unfortunately i can't ssh into that server.. i think i'll open a ticket to the system administraor and hope to find a solution with him

Comment: However if i call the command from a route in this way Artisan::call(MyCommand) is all ok.. but wher i use php artisan MyCommand in the cron job, it doesn't work !!!!! WHY!?!?! :)

Comment: Hi Brian, the problem was on the server! Now is all ok, the system administator has done an update on cron command.. i don't know.. but now is all ok! 
Thanks for you time

Comment: Your welcome. Glad you got it sorted out. I know how frustrating things like this can be.